# Google App Engine post request query string

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm building my first GAE app. After watching a tutorial video on youtube, ([this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfgO-LXGpTM)) I noticed that when a post request is made, say from a form, yo don't see the querystring in the URL (my desired behavior).

The surprise arises when I perform a post request from a form, conceptually the same one that's on the video, and the query string is displayed in the URL (not so desired behavior).

Is this something like a default behavior or something? Can I hide those querystring parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you talk about the HTTP methods like POST or GET,
check the attribute "method" in your form definition, you need to put it to "POST" like

```
<form action="" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

You can see more informations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

Comment: I have never heard of any library (on or off App Engine) which uses query strings for a POST by default. Without specific information I'd guess with sahid that you are actually grappling with an HTML form problem that would arise just as much off of App Engine, like the one he points out.

Comment: now I'm really ashamed... I got the word "methos" instead of "method" on the HTML tag! found out after posting! sorry for make you waste your time guys, really appreciate the help.

Comment: It's not a matter of libraries - this is how HTTP works. Query strings can be used in any request, since they're part of the URL, but only HTML forms set to 'get' will modify the query string.